# How to reduce the brightness of the highlight area

Tags: rendering

I made a kitchen scene. I found the highlights of the sink(green) on the right are so bright. How can I lower this highlight?
[image]
[image]

Comment: what happens when you turn down the specular value in your principled shader?

Comment: you can try to increase roughness and lower down metallic

Comment: Maybe you need to lower down some lights (or maybe it's your HDRI)?